# Can I use the Netduino USB as a serial port?

Tags: arduino, netduino

A [serial port demo](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/366-netduino-serial-port-code-review/) shows how to use GPIOs to communicate through a second USB connection.

But as a Arduino developer I'm used to use the same USB for both programming and runtime communication.

Can I do the same with Netduino?

Comment: I've seen some netduino forum posts saying that it is not possible with a given version of the firmware. I wonder if the latest versions enable this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Netduino uses the USB port for communicating the debugging information required so you can live debug through visual studio.

It is possible to switch the Netduino and use an FTDI serial cable to do the programming/debugging which will leave the USB port free for communications. There is a thread about this [on the Netduino forums](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/178-serial-communication-between-the-computer-and-the-netduino/).

There are also discussions [here](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/449-serial-comms-via-usb-in-the-cards/) and [here](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/481-serialread-via-usb-yu-know-like-on-the-good-ol-arduino/page__p__3549__hl__serial__fromsearch__1#entry3549) that confirm they are working on the problem.